# How to asynchronously print a message and modify it?

Tags: python, asynchronous, input

So I've been trying to use the asyncio library, and...

**Here is my objective : making a program that displays a message periodically. That message can be modified anytime by the user.**

I feel like I'm close to the solution with the following code, but there is one issue I can't seem to resolve.

```
import asyncio
import msvcrt

class PeriodicMessage():
    def __init__(self, message="This is a periodic message. Press M to modify it."):
        self.message = message

    async def write_message(self, sleep_delay=1):
        while True:
            print(self.message)
            await asyncio.sleep(sleep_delay)

    async def change_message(self, sleep_delay=0.01):
        while True:
            if msvcrt.kbhit():
                key_pressed = msvcrt.getch() or None
                if key_pressed == b'm':
                    self.message = input("Enter a new message to display : ")
            await asyncio.sleep(sleep_delay)

    async def main(self):
        await asyncio.gather(self.write_message(), self.change_message())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    periodic_msg = PeriodicMessage()
    asyncio.run(periodic_msg.main())
```

If you run this, you'll see that the message is indeed shown periodically. And you can press M to modify the message. However, the issue seems to be that the "input()" function blocks the program, making it not really asynchronous anymore. I've read somewhere that an asynchronous input in python is not really a thing, but I couldn't confirm it since I saw that from only one source.

Maybe I'm completely wrong and the solution I'm exploring right now is just not right.

Any idea ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to accomplish your task is to install package `aioconsole` from the `PyPI` repository and use:

```
self.message = await ainput("Enter a new message to display: ")
```

Of course, in your demo, your constant outputting of messages (""This is a periodic message ...") interferes somewhat with demonstrating this, so I have changed the message slightly and lengthened the period between outputting the message:

```
import asyncio
from aioconsole import ainput

class PeriodicMessage():
    def __init__(self, message="This is a periodic message. Enter new text to modify it."):
        self.message = message

    async def write_message(self, sleep_delay=5):
        while True:
            print(self.message)
            await asyncio.sleep(sleep_delay)

    async def change_message(self):
        while True:
            self.message = await ainput("Enter a new message to display: ")

    async def main(self):
        await asyncio.gather(self.write_message(), self.change_message())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    periodic_msg = PeriodicMessage()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(periodic_msg.main())
```

Comment: It works very nicely, thanks!
I'll try to work on a UI for that next, I'll see what I can come up with!